# Unity Draw Ellipse at an angle

Tags: unity-game-engine, ellipse, drawellipse

This one has me stumped.

I've got code to draw ellipses etc in Unity. It all works great. But at the moment I only get horizontal ellipses or vertical ellipses by changing the major and minor axes.

**What I really need is to be able to draw ellipses at angle, tilted, skewiff, NOT straight up or sideways.**

Please help. Even better if it can be done using standard draw ellipse code.

Comment: Could you, please, post the code you are using? It might help trying to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how do you draw ellipses because you haven't post any code but this is how you can calculate points on tilted ellipse

```
var resolution = 50; //resolution of ellipse
var a = 50;
var b = 20;
var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(45,0,0); //set your angles here
for(var i = 0f; i < 2*Mathf.PI; i+=2*Mathf.PI/resolution){
    var vector = new Vector3( a*Mathf.Cos(i) ,0, b*Mathf.Sin(i) );
    vector = rotation*vector; // you can multiply vector by quaternion to get tilted ellipse

    //you can do something with vector here

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(45,0,0); //set your angles here
vector = rotation*vector;
That's what I needed.